# Prepositions: On a map vs In a map

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between "on the map" or "in the map"? Is one of them grammatically incorrect? Thanks!

Comment: Why should only one of them be correct?

Comment: Are both of them correct? Then what is the difference? Thanks!